# Parameters display in intellisense

Tags: c#, parameters, intellisense

Why does 'Parameter' fields are shown as ending with : 'Colon' in Intelli sense. For instance

```
public void calculate(int x, int y)
{
    DisplayInConsole(x, y);
}
```

The above is a simple method which passes the parameters to another method, However, when typing `DisplayInConsole(` Intellisense displays `x, x:, y, y:`. I know that `x:` defines the parameters but is there any particular reason to separate it from `x`. Why don't we use `x` directly? Even if you use `x:` it points to variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you could, if you wished, specify the parameters in a different order than those given, through use of `x:` and `y:`.

Take a look at the following example:

```
calculate(y: 4, x: 2);
```

This, functionally, is identical to:

```
calculate(2, 4);
```

However, I have chosen to express `y:` first and `x:` second in the top example.

Comment: Thanks Martin, But when you select 'x:' in intellisense why is it still displaying as x, rather than x:. If I want to specify as calculate(y:4, x:2), I need to type the ':' right??

Comment: @Darey I believe Intellisense is offering you the opportunity to explicitly specify which parameter you are specifying, hence displaying `x:` and `y:`.  This is only apparent in your `calculate` function because your parameters are also called `x` and `y`.  Rename them temporarily to `a` and `b`, and you will see that Intellisense will only offer `x:` and `y:` with the colon, and `a` and `b` will appear as normal.  In short, this is a feature of the fact that you have input parameters to `calculate` named `x` and `y` and also parameters to `DisplayInConsole` named `x` and `y`.